# Is "mate" in the word "roommate" a root or a suffix?

Tags: etymology

I'm doing my term paper about wordbuilding. And I'm interested what is "mate" in the word "roommate"? Is it a second root so the word "roommate" is a compound, or is it a suffix?

Comment: What research have you yourself done? Have you, for example, looked at the Wikipedia article for [affixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix), where the third line on the page will tell you the answer quite clearly?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe for a native speaker it's quite a simple question) and I followed your advise, but didn't find anything helpful, or I'm just blind) I'm analysing the word building tendency on basis of David Mitchell's "Cloud Atlas".

Comment: From Wikipedia: “[Affixes] are [bound morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_morpheme) by definition”. ‘Mate’ is not a bound morpheme: it appears on its own as a fully-fledged noun meaning ‘friend, comrade’.

Comment: do a simple test: say "a roommate is a type of mate." if this is true, then your compound word is an endocentric compound whose root is *mate*.

Comment: Although I must say so in more than 15 characters, the answer to the presenting question is precisely ***Yes***. One can consider it either way, and many do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All words ultimately lead to roots.

Both *room* and *mate* would trace the roots.  *Mate*=*partner* from *mette*=*guest*. *Room* is a Germanic word from *Raum*.

In your example of *roommate*, it is a Noun+Noun compound word as in *shipmate*.